# Twitter bootstrap grid guide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am hoping someone can help me with this I am slightly confused with this I have always worked with 960 grid system. Making a Responsive design with Twitter Bootstrap, see the problem I am having is that the Desktop view on the twitter site states

Label   Layout width    Column width    Gutter width
Large display   1200px and up   70px    30px
Default 980px and up    60px    20px
Portrait tablets    768px and above 42px    20px
Phones to tablets   767px and below Fluid columns, no fixed widths
Phones  480px and below Fluid columns, no fixed widths

Surely it should be Default 960px and up? with 60*12 + 20* = 960px?

Is is there something I am missing or is it simply will need to use the customizer?

Basically should the size of my PSD be 940px still (as it would normally?) or should it be 960px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surely it should be Default 960px and up? with 60*12 + 20* = 960px?

If you allow for 20px padding before the first column, 20px between each each column and 20px after the last column the total is 12*(60+20) + 20 = 980px

> should the size of my PSD be 940px still (as it would normally?) or
>   should it be 960px?

Yes, design for 940px wide. As long as the device window is 980px or more it will display full width.

If you are coming from 960.gs, the design width is the same. The difference is that bootstap has an extra 10px margin at the start and end of every row so it needs a 980px wide window to display full width.

If you are looking for bootstap layout templates for the different widths, here is one good source https://benstewart.net/2012/06/bootstrap-responsive-photoshop-templates/

Comment: That is what I thought but wanted clarification thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

From bootstrap, this is correct...

- Large display    1200px and up
- Default  980px and up
- Portrait tablets     768px and above
- Phones to tablets    767px and below
- Phones   480px and below

Comment: Hi I know that, and that is why I am asking the question is Twitter Bootstrap 980 Grid? or is there something I am missing and turn it into 960grid I need to do something else instead?